# How to add custom color to extjs bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I am trying to add custom color and other styles to bar chart using extjs bar chart, I looking to styles to be done in plugin properties kindly the series one.
**here is my code**

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.chart.Chart'
]);

Ext.define('CricketScore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['month', 'data1' ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'CricketScore',
            data: [
                { month: 'Jan', data1: 20 },
                { month: 'Feb', data1: 20 },
                { month: 'Mar', data1: 19 },
                { month: 'Apr', data1: 18 },
                { month: 'May', data1: 18 },
                { month: 'Jun', data1: 17 },
                { month: 'Jul', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Aug', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Sep', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Oct', data1: 16 },
                { month: 'Nov', data1: 15 },
                { month: 'Dec', data1: 15 }
            ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
   //renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   renderTo: "demoChart",
   width: 400,
   height: 300,
    store: store,
    animate: true,
   axes: [
       {
                type: 'Numeric',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['data1'],
                minimum: 0,
                maximum:100

            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'top',
                fields: ['month'],
            }
    ],

      series: [
       {
                type: 'column',
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'month',
                yField: 'data1',
                style :{
                    fill : '#343234',
                    'stroke-width': 30
                },
                highlight: {
                    fill: '#cd1c5f',
                    'stroke-width': 10,
                    stroke: '#ed2b74'
                },
                tips: {
                    trackMouse: true,
                    style: 'background: #FFF',
                    height: 20,
                    renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                        this.setTitle(storeItem.get('month') + ': ' + storeItem.get('data1') + '%');
                    }
                }
            }
    ]
});
```

**here is Jisfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/djaydxnd/54/

Comment: Which ExtJS version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle you are using `ExtJS 4.2` then I am assuming that you are using **4.2** verison. To give color you have to write `renderer` and `getLegendColor` function in `series` object

```
getLegendColor: function(index) {
                return 'rgb(255,203,36)';
              },
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                return Ext.apply(attr, {
                 fill: 'rgb(255,203,36)'
                });
              }
```

Hope this helps.

In `ExtJA 6` you can directly use `colors` property of `series` object.

Comment: Its works perfectly, but can you differentiate  "getLegendColor:function()"  and renderer: function(...), because i want know use both function or any one?

if you have any sample link or doc for this

Comment: If you using legend in your char like small square on right hand side then you have to write that code. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/example/charts/Pie.html I. if you are not using it then it is not required to write that function.

Comment: I have one more concern, I need to bring data values as shown in the image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO56l.png) for bottom axis, but its coming like a range of value 0,10,15,20 etc

Comment: I am giving that answer in your another question. This Answer resolve your question.